# Should I reach out to my future advisor before accepting PhD admission?

Tags: phd, thesis-committee

I have been offered PhD admission which I have not accepted yet.I have already been assigned advisors though.

I want to reach out to my potential advisor to discuss future research and maybe even dissertation topics ? Was wondering if that is okay for to do ? i am little hesitant because I am not sure if this is the norm for how things are done ?

Comment: Related questions: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/4793/why-would-one-choose-a-particular-advisor-other-than-having-shared-interests http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/66926/ive-been-admitted-to-multiple-phd-programs-how-should-i-choose-between-them/66928#66928 http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/48616/good-questions-for-a-student-advisor-compatibility-test

Answer (score 4):

Yes. If you're certain about the advisor you'll be working with, feel free to get in contact with them. Even if you change advisors before beginning the program - or even if you don't join that program - it will not hurt to introduce yourself and to start planning.